# jackson - How to deserialize empty as null

Tags: java, jackson

I've got a POJO with several String properties

```
public class Pojo {
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 ....
//getters...
//settesr...
```

Whats the best way to tell Jackson to destabilize the properties so that empty strings will map to NULL values.
I do no wish to do that in the getters (as I have a lot of POJO properties), is there a simple annotation for that (on the class level)?

Comment: ^ Use the answer above to define a deserializer, then annotate your field with `@JsonDeserialize`, using that deserializer.

Comment: Thanks, however i do not wish to add an `@JsonDeserializ` for each field (this is too verbose). I'm looking for a class annotation to do that...

Comment: There isn't one. You can register the deserializer for all `String` fields.

Answer (score 3):

Configure your mapper to enable the [ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features#value-conversions-coercion) feature.

> Determines whether empty String value is accepted as null value for regular POJOs ("beans") with data-binding: this can be useful when dealing endpoints written in a language that has loose typing and may represent missing objects as Empty Strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however String is not considered as a regular POJO. Thus, in my example, the lastName property is still set to an empty string ("") in case the json that is serialized is: {"firstNsme": "'john", "lastName": ""}

Comment: The linked post in the comments already explains why this doesn't work for `String`s.